# grails, spring security ui plugin - invitation link

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm using spring security ui plugin. I have admin user who can create all other users. Every user has email and when admin registers a user app should send email to the user with the invitation link.

Then by clicking on invitation link user should see a page where its possible to specify a password.

I know that plugin has some similar feature but its not exactly what I want. Is it possible to customize plugins behaviour without changing plugin's code?

Thanks!

P.S. Sorry if the question sounds silly I'm new to grails :)

Comment: how you are using 'username' in spring security ui plugin.

Comment: its used just for login

Comment: that user name is provided in your invitation or can  be choosen by user

Comment: I saw the code, the users are able to register with custom usernames.

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky, you may try to override plugin classes just by placing them in the same structure order as they are located inside plugin. Sometimes that works, sometimes didn't.